# Setting Cookies with Poltergeist PhantomJS Capybara Driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I'm running to issues attempting to set cookies using the Poltergeist gem, and from reading through the closed issues at the Poltergeist gem, it appears this is a user error issue on my part, but I've spent a full day now on attempting to get the cookies set properly, and I can't seem to set things up properly.

Note: This test works fine in selenium, but I'd like to use poltergeist due to run time issues with selenium.

The application I'm working on is using "_location" cookie to determine some overall settings, and I need to have the cookie accessible on my first visit of any page in the application. Otherwise I get a javascript error looking for a value that is not set due to the location not being set.

[The README for the Poltergeist gem](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) shows the following usage for cookies

Manipulating cookies

The following methods are used to inspect and manipulate cookies:

`page.driver.cookies` - a hash of cookies accessible to the current page. The keys are cookie names. The values are Cookie objects, with the following methods: `name`, `value`, `domain`, `path`, `secure?`, `httponly?`, `expires`.

`page.driver.set_cookie(name, value, options = {})` - set a cookie. The options hash can take the following keys: `:domain`, `:path`, `:secure`, `:httponly`, `:expires`. `:expires` should be a Time object.

`page.driver.remove_cookie(name)` - remove a cookie

-- specs/spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :debug => true)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

-- views/admin/article/new.html.haml

```
= link_to_function "test js", '$(this).html("js works")'
```

-- specs/requests/article_products_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Associating Articles with Products and Product Categories" do

  before (:all) do
    @user = create(:user, role: "admin")
    5.times { create(:product_category) }
    @product_categories = ProductCategory.all
    @product_categories.each do |pc|
      4.times { create(:product, product_category: pc) }
    end
  end

  before (:each) do
    visit new_user_session_path
    page.driver.set_cookie("_location", "US")
    page.driver.cookies
    fill_in "Username Or Email", with: @user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @user.password
    click_button "Sign In"
    visit new_admin_article_path
  end

  it "supports js", :js => true do
    click_link "test js"
    page.should have_content("js works")
  end

end
```

test response

```
{"name"=>"visit", "args"=>["http://127.0.0.1:64554/users/sign_in"]}
{"error"=>{"name"=>"Poltergeist.JavascriptError", "args"=>[[{"message"=>"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')", "stack"=>"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:12338\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1076\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1194\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:7539 in done\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:8325"}]]}}
{"name"=>"reset", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>true}
F

Failures:

  1) Associating Articles with Products and Product Categories supports js
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_session_path
     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page:

       TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:12338
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1076
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1194
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:7539 in done
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:8325
     # ./spec/requests/article_products_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/vcr.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

With this failure, I thought perhaps I should be setting the cookies before visiting the page, however it appears that when I use the page.driver.set_cookie command before I use "visit" in my Capybara scripts, it doesn't actually set anything. As seen from this modified code block and this result set.

-- specs/requests/article_products_spec.rb

```
describe "Associating Articles with Products and Product Categories" do

  before (:all) do
    @user = create(:user, role: "admin")
    5.times { create(:product_category) }
    @product_categories = ProductCategory.all
    @product_categories.each do |pc|
      4.times { create(:product, product_category: pc) }
    end
  end

  before (:each) do
    page.driver.set_cookie("_location", "US")
    page.driver.cookies
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in "Username Or Email", with: @user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: @user.password
    click_button "Sign In"
    visit new_admin_article_path
  end

  it "supports js", :js => true do
    click_link "test js"
    page.should have_content("js works")
  end
end
```

test response

```
{"name"=>"set_cookie", "args"=>[{:name=>"_location", :value=>"US", :domain=>"127.0.0.1"}]}
{"response"=>true}
{"name"=>"cookies", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>[]}
{"name"=>"visit", "args"=>["http://127.0.0.1:64090/users/sign_in"]}
{"error"=>{"name"=>"Poltergeist.JavascriptError", "args"=>[[{"message"=>"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')", "stack"=>"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64090/assets/non_deferred.js:12338\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64090/assets/non_deferred.js:1076\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64090/assets/non_deferred.js:1194\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64090/assets/non_deferred.js:7539 in done\n    at http://127.0.0.1:64090/assets/non_deferred.js:8325"}]]}}
{"name"=>"reset", "args"=>[]}
{"response"=>true}
F

Failures:

  1) Associating Articles with Products and Product Categories supports js
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_session_path
     Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError:
       One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page:

       TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'response.custentitydefault_shipping_location')
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:12338
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1076
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:1194
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:7539 in done
           at http://127.0.0.1:64554/assets/non_deferred.js:8325
     # ./spec/requests/article_products_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/vcr.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've also attempted to pass in a phantomjs_options block to the poltergeist driver, with an external cookies file. That actually appeared to get me a bit farther, but I ended up with a null cookie_jar. You can see this attempt below:

--spec/spec_helper.rb

```
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, [phantomjs_options: [--cookies-file="#{::Rails.root}/spec/requests/cookies.txt"]] )
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

-- cookies.txt

```
phantom.addCookie({
    'name':     '_location',
    'value':    'US',
    'domain':   'localhost',
    'expires':  (new Date()).getTime() + 3600
});
```

test response
    F

```
Failures:

  1) Associating Articles with Products and Product Categories supports js
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_session_path
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `cookie_jar' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/article_products_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/vcr.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.42 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your attempt to specify options to Poltergeist got confused with options to PhantomJS.  Your registration block should look like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :phantomjs_options => ["--cookies-file=#{::Rails.root}/spec/requests/cookies.txt"])
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, we ended up going a different route, but your explanation looks correct.